# Does a list of errata for Ashcroft and Mermin's Solid State Physics exist?

Tags: solid-state-physics, specific-reference, textbook-erratum

I have tried Googling a list of errata for A&M, but it does not seem to exist. Has anyone found one?

Comment: Typically erratum require someone to keep it updated; since [both Mermin & Ashcroft have retired](http://www.lassp.cornell.edu/people/emeritus), I doubt their interest lies in doing so (especially since they've had no 2nd edition of their book).

Comment: @KyleKanos that makes sense, but the book was published in the 70s, so I figured someone would have taken the time in the interim.